# google endpoint - datastore - filter by property

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new to "Google app engine" and i would like to ask a question.

I have used Eclipse plugin to create google endpoints and backend for this sample Android application. 
I have succesfully created 2 entities in datastore and i tried to get one of these entries from datastore. I can use listuser (the class is named user) and then filter on values but i don't think it will be a good solution. Therefore i want to use simple filtering based on one user class properties (not the key). I have failed so far, and would like to ask you to have a quick answer to that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to provide an Endpoint method that will allow you to search for your User entities based on some parameters that you pass. And these parameters would be the class properties or Entity attributes.

If that is indeed the case, you can absolutely do that. Simply create an additional Endpoint method and make sure to identify the parameters that will be passed to the method. Then in the method implementation, depending on whether you are using JDO / JPA - you will need to use the correct Query methods to retrieve the entities.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `@Index` to the property in other to use it as a filter